# jQuery window.location.replace keeps looping

Tags: jquery, browser, kill, window.location

I'm using window.location.replace() with jQuery to redirect to a new page in wordpres if you got a older browser in either Internet explorer or Firefox due to my html5 layout.

```
              var browser = jQuery.browser;
              var version = browser.version.slice(0.3);

              if ( browser.msie && version != "10.0" && version != '9.0' ) {
                    window.location.replace("http://crosscom.dk/update-browser");
              }

               if ( browser.mozilla && version != "17.0" && version != '16.0' && version != '15.0' ) {
                    window.location.replace("http://crosscom.dk/update-browser/");
              }
```

The redirects works but since its loaded in the header in wordpres it keeps on looping everytime, you are sitting on: example IE 8.

So my question is following...

How can i kill the script or setup different parameters around my code to stop the script from looping after the browser got redirected once?

Comment: If you're redirecting to a new page, why does the new page still have the redirect code?

Comment: Hmmm, what does `slice(0.3)` (zero point three) do? And what happens if the version is a fraction, e.g. `15.1`, `16.2`?

Comment: Slicing basicly tells that when identifying the browser it looks for a version like 10.1 rather than only 10. Thats at least how i think it works. I found it on another thread

Comment: slice() gives the same result as slice(0.3) because 0.3 is an invalid parameter for slice. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop is caused because the redirection occurs no matter what page you are on, including the redirection target. To avoid a loop, test whether you are already in the redirect location.

There are a number of ways this could be achieved - the most efficient probably being a server side check and redirection. However, on the assumption that your knowledge level or deployment requirements mean that a JavaScript alternative is better, you could use the following code:

```
var redirectLocation = "http://example.com/example.html"; // Redirect destination

// Page location and redirectLocation should not be the same
if (window.location.href !== redirectLocation) {
  // Redirect logic
}
```

Applying this directly to your own code example produces:

```
var browser = jQuery.browser;
var version = browser.version.slice(0.3);
var redirectLocation = "http://crosscom.dk/update-browser/"; // Redirect destination

// Page location and redirectLocation should not be the same 
if (window.location.href !== redirectLocation) { 
  // Redirect logic

  if ( browser.msie && version != "10.0" && version != '9.0' ) {
    window.location.replace(redirectLocation);
  }

  if ( browser.mozilla && version != "17.0" && version != '16.0' && version != '15.0' ) {
    window.location.replace(redirectLocation);
  }

}
```

Comment: By using this code, Don't you tell only if you already are on the specific URL you redirect rather than doing both things simuntanisly?

Comment: I tryed using the code snippet allthough without any results. Nothing happened. And no error messages.

Comment: It's missing a bracket. I've edited the code - could you try it again? The line I added checks the URL of the page you are on, and if the current page matches the redirect then it does not redirect.

Comment: I've tryed your code, but i didnt work... i did some changes to it now like adding .href after location changing the URL so it had a backslash after since apparantly that was the correct syntax on my website. besides that i changed the if you are on the current URL stage, rewrote it a bit and then it worked :) so thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Only include the script on pages where redirection is needed

Comment: Well i need to run the script no matter which page they are on, so they user experience is flawlessly.

Comment: @fragstar not that particular script

Comment: Arent that a bit overkill if i can include it once?